# How to configure Spring Security properly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I've got a problem configuring SpringSecurity. This is my configuration class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration

public class SecurityConfiguration{

    private final UserService userService;
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth)-> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
            auth.requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN");
            auth.requestMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER");
          })
           .userDetailsService(userService)
           .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and here is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return ("<h1>Welcome</h1>");
    }
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String homeUser(){
        return ("<h1>Welcome user </h1>");
    }
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String homeAdmin(){
        return ("<h1>Welcome admin </h1>");
    }
}
```

As I understand, while visiting localhost address I should be able to see `<h1>Welcome</h1>` tag without authentication needed, but when I try to access the address, the login form appears. When I log in as an user or admin, I get HTTP 403 response.

Here is rest of my project files:
Role model:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="role_id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

User model

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    )
    private List <Role> roles;

    public User(String username, String password, List <Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection <? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(authorities.getClass());
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

User repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository <User, Long>{
    Optional <User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Role repository

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Role findByName(String name);
}
```

UserService

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository
                .findByUsername(username)
                .map(User::new)
                .orElseThrow(()->new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: "+username));
    }
}
```

This is class with the main method that adds roles and users to the database:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(UserRepository users, RoleRepository roles, PasswordEncoder encoder){
        return args->{
            Role adminRole = roles.save(new Role("ADMIN"));
            Role userRole = roles.save(new Role("USER"));

            List<Role> userRoles = Arrays.asList(userRole);
            List<Role> adminRoles = Arrays.asList(adminRole, userRole);

            users.save(new User("user", encoder.encode("user"), userRoles));
            users.save(new User("admin", encoder.encode("admin"), adminRoles));
        };
    }

}
```

application.yaml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/demo
    username: root
    password: ""
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    database: mysql
server:
  port: 8081
```

I'm using mysql on xampp and after starting the app, everything seems to be working fine. There are records in the user, role and user_role tables.

I think have already tried every possible combination of requestMatchers() with just "/", "/**", "/user", "/user/**". I have also tried using @EnableMethodSecurity with the same result. I think it might be something to do with the Authorities but after logging that to console, it returns correct roles.

Comment: Your question became part of the source code. Please fix the formatting and maybe put it at the bottom or the top of the question. I haven't notice it at first.

Comment: Do you get a login dialogue when accessing admin content? And does the access work, when you provide correct credentials?

Comment: For me whenever i setup up security and have some problems i go to security filter chain and debug, that is the only way that you can be sure where you messed up. Check this article https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security and start debugging from org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager where all authentication provider are ran.

Comment: May i ask for the reason as to why you havn’t just enabled spring security debug logs and read the reason for the 403 before asking here?

Comment: As @Toerktumlare said, add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties`

Comment: @ValerijDobler I get login page when I try to access /user or /admin, but when I provide correct data I still get 403 error

Comment: I enabled logs and just before 403 response I get:
`Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User(id=null, username=admin, password=$2a$1..., roles=[Role(id=1, name=ADMIN), Role(id=2, name=USER)]), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=45C4F...], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN, USER]] ` and `Sending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User(id=null, username=admin...`

Comment: the next line is just `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied`

Comment: please dont include the logs in comment, you can edit your question, please use that function, and include the full logs, not just a snippet. We want the context

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your public content behind the mapping `/public` and adjust the matchers like so:

```java
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth)-> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .requestMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
            .requestMatchers("/public").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated());
        }
```

Comment: .anyRequest().authenticated() won’t demand logging in on any request, including these which match “/public”?

Comment: .anyRequest().authenticated() means that spring security will ask for authentication to access the services other then `/public`. only services which comes under `/public` are allowed to access without authentication.

Comment: As @DhrumanDesai said. It applies for anything else, which you didn't provide a matcher. This also includes `/admin/something-else` , for matching this also only with ADMIN role use an AntMatcher instead.

Comment: after changing the mapping to:
`@GetMapping("/public")
    public String home(){
        return ("<h1>Welcome</h1>");
    }`
i still can't get access without loggin in. I have tried this request on postman **http://localhost:8081/public**
and it returns log in form